# Present perfect tense "duration"

Tags: past-tense, since

Ten years ago I bought a new jacket.
Now it is ten years long. I know that I can't say "I have bought this jacket for ten years". But I want to show duration now and to emphasize duration how long I have bought.
Can I say:

> It has been ten years **since** I bought that jacket.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. "Now it is ten years long" is incorrect, and is not necessary: the first sentence explains everything. :"....how long I have bought" is also incorrect: you should sayh "how long **ago** I bought **it**".

Comment: Thank you very much@JavaLatte.How about "It is ten years long."and "Now it has been ten years."These questions are not related with context and I just ask you can I use them in other expressions and are they correct expressions.

Comment: "It is ten years long": you use the word "long" when you are talking about the duration of  something, not the time relative to now. For example, "I want to become a brain surgeon, but the course is ten years long".  "It has been ten years **since** ...." states that it is ten years since some event. "Now" is superfluous, because present perfect means it's a time relative to now.

Comment: Thank you so much@JavaLatte.You gave me three facts.Thanks.

Comment: This is correct, but that's not a very useful answer. Please use the "Edit" button to say more about why you had concern that it might *not* be correct, and then the answer can be more substantial. I'm voting to close for now but will retract my vote after it's edited.

Comment: Your sentence is correct but your paragraph has various mistakes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more natural to state, "I have *owned* this jacket for ten years."

"Bought" describes a single event, at a single point in time. If it is a long process, I'd use the infinitive, "It took us three months *to buy* our house."

"Owned" has more of a concept of duration. "I've owned this car since I left college."

Comment: I accept @DrWoishe Pippik